# Any Alternative Transparent Flash in VB6

Tags: flash, video, vb6, transparent

I am trying to put transparent Flash content over the video. using Shockwave Flash I have tried much time but not possible to make it workable at run time.

Please provide me any alternative ActiveX to run transparent Flash over video or overlay. How to resolve this issue?

[Project Picture Flash Over Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqb6R.png)

[image]

Comment: PS: **Not clear** what is the exact problem? What are your Flash [**display settings**](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?606123-Transparent-Flash-problem&p=3746384&viewfull=1#post3746384)? Where in above photo is the Flash content? If the content is static (eg: a logo or a heading) why not just use a transparent PNG since that picture format supports alpha (transparency) channel... Anyways does the Flash have transparency?

Comment: actually want to put animated transparent logo. which is used to make in flash player. i have created the logo in flash swf format and put over the video. but this will not support transparency.